# NSButton titlecolor in IB for checkbox-type

Tags: macos, cocoa

How do I set the color of the title of an NSButton with type 'checkbox'? The fontsize accepts the input from the fontpicker, the coloer, however, does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this-

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedButtonTitle = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Put the title of your choice"];
[attributedButtonTitle addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[NSColor blueColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,[@"Put the title of your choice" length] )];
[buttonWithTypeCheckBox setAttributedTitle:attributedButtonTitle];
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi! It doesn't work as expected, but that seems to be due to my obviously misguided perception of how viewcontrollers are used in cocoa as opposed to cocoa-touch. So, basically, yes it work that way ;)